# How to put Rule(check) on installation of certain set of files/folders?

Tags: install4j

Like in InstallWhere we put rule over the installation step of files and folders. How could we achieve the same in Install4j. Like it should check the value of some installer variable before installing the file. Please help in this regard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create different file sets in the Files->Define Distribution Tree step. Each file set has an ID. IDs can be shown by toggling the "Show IDs" tool bar button.

In the installer, you can then call

```
context.getFileSetById("[ID]").setSelected(false)
```

on order to not install the files in the file set, where [ID] is replaced by the actual ID of the file set.